# How to print the if statement in C

Tags: c, optimization

I am learning C and decided to play around with the code. I can figure out the password as it has a bug in my code by writing any character but at 108 character writing the letter `K` which overwrite tha `trigger` variable and I can print the message `inside`. I was wondering is there a way to do the same printing the message `inside` by changing the return address in my code? If any more details are needed please let me know.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
char getdata() {
  int trigger = 'A';
  char data[100];
  gets(data);
  return (char) trigger;
}
void login() {
  printf("inside!\n");
  exit(0);
}
void main() {
  printf("enter ");
  if (getdata() == 'K') {
    login();
  } else {
    printf("wrong.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

I want the output to be:
When user enter some password could be anything it should print `inside` and that should even work while I have Address Space Layout
Randomisation on.

Comment: @Inian Sorry that was a typo. I have edited my code.

Comment: Don't use `gets()` function!  See [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/5291015)

Comment: what do you want, to read a char or a string ?

Comment: @bruno I want to be able to print the message `inside` by changing the return address, so it does not matter I guess if its a string or char.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add an example of input, as well as the actual and the expected output.

Comment: @Sky currently *getdata* always return 'A' => `(getdata() == 'K')` is always false and you cannot call *inside*

Comment: @bruno Yeah, I know that so is there a way to make it work by changing the return address?

Comment: what about to have `char getdata()  { return getchar(); }`  ? or directely to replace call to *getdata* by *getchar* ? The problem is not the return *adress* by *value*

Comment: @bruno If I do that can I print the message `inside`? If so could you explain a bit more please

Comment: @Sky just replace the definition, compile then run your program an enter K

Comment: @Sky look at my answer

Comment: @bruno If I do that and enter K it prints nothing and if I press enter again it prints `wrong` rather `inside`

Comment: @Sky again look at my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

if I well understand you want something like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
char getdata() {
  return getchar();
}
void login() {
  printf("inside!\n");
  exit(0);
}
int main() {  // warning main returns an int, not void
  printf("enter ");
  if (getdata() == 'K') {
    login();
  } else {
    printf("wrong.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall c.c
/tmp % ./a.out
enter K
inside!
/tmp % ./a.out
enter s
wrong.
/tmp %
```

(in the first case I enter `K<return>` and in the second `s<return>`, but whatever the character(s) entered after the first character because they are not read)

Comment: Yes, it works. But, is it possible to change return address but still keep the rest of the code inside `getdata()` so not changing a lot except return address?

Comment: since the beginning I do not understand what you mean by `return address`, please can you explain ?

Comment: I mean I need to make the same code work while the ASLR is on as well. Do you think this will work?

Comment: @Sky *ASLR* ? what is that

Comment: It is Address Space Layout
Randomisation

Comment: @Sky again and again **address of what ?**

Comment: By address I meant `return address of getdata()`

Comment: *getdata* is declared to return a *char*, it does not return an address. I already asked you to know if you want to read char or a string ...

Comment: What do you think would be considered return address in  all of my code then? I am new to C so not sure.

Comment: what you say have no sense, you can get/return the address of a function/variable but not *all the code*, and what for ? you are very unclear

Comment: Sorry, all I meant is to make it print `inside` by changing the return address. If a function can get/return the address then there is only one function we can change which is `getdata()`, so I meant that.